# Cant view products under categories in magento 2.4.3

Tags: php, magento, adobe, product, magento2.4

Im trying to upgrade our magento commerce site from 2.4.1 to 2.4.3 in a staging environment - Ive almost got it working but Ive found that when navigating through the category tree at the lowest level no products are being displayed just the message

We can't find products matching the selection.

Ive seen this before and tried all the usual suggestions

- reindex
- clear cache
- flush cache
- purge front page cache

With no luck. Searching for products and viewing results works fine.

Ive also tried solutions posted here

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/products-not-showing-in-category-on-frontend-Magento-2-but/td-p/143481

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135814/products-are-not-showing-in-category-magento-2

https://digitalstartup.co.uk/t/products-not-showing-in-categories-but-are-there-in-the-database-and-backend/1838/11

This has lead me to find that there is an issue editing product attributtes in the admin section, I get a js error on load of the attributtes, the data loads but I cannot save them.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
    at switchDefaultValueField ((index):1279)
    at bindAttributeInputType ((index):1120)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):1389)
    at fire (jquery.min.js:212)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery.min.js:215)
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.min.js:223)
    at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.min.js:200)
    at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-migrate.min.js:27)
    at jQuery (jquery.min.js:16)
    at (index):1388
```

I have tried setting the attributes to non filterable and none searchable at SQL level but no luck.

This works fine in 2.4.1, and the only change is the upgrade

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try these, test on each,
/usr/bin/php74 bin/magento c:f)
/usr/bin/php74 bin/magento catalog:images:resize
/usr/bin/php74 bin/magento indexer:reset
/usr/bin/php74 bin/magento indexer:reindex
/usr/bin/php74 bin/magento cache:clean full_page block_html
/usr/bin/php74 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Answer (score 0):

do you check elasticsearch ?

In my case, when i fix connection with elasticsearch server remotely, i solve this problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).